# How to enable pinch zoom on a Mac WebView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview, pinchzoom

I've already searched "everything" about this in Google/Stackoverflow, but I'm still stuck. I have just started developing OSX Apps, so I'm a (almost) complete newbie in Objective-C and Xcode 5 (5.0.2).

All I need is a simple webview to load a webgame from a given URL. This webview must behave just like a very simple Safari browser. My app is already working relatively well. It loads the game OK, and after a lot of struggling I succeeded making it show javascript alerts and confirms.

My task is now make the pinch zoom work. That's my appDelegate.M:

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

    @implementation AppDelegate

    @synthesize myWebView;

    // Enables confirms:
    - (BOOL)webView:(WebView *)sender runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    NSInteger result = NSRunInformationalAlertPanel(NSLocalizedString(@"Confirmação", @""),  // title
    message,                // message
    NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @""),      // default button
    NSLocalizedString(@"Cancelar", @""),    // alt button
    nil);

    return NSAlertDefaultReturn == result;  
    }

    // Enables alerts:
    - (void)webView:(WebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
        NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
        [alert setMessageText:message];
        [alert runModal];
        //[alert release];
    }

    // This was supposed to enable pinch zoom:
    - (void)magnifyWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
        //[resultsField setStringValue:
         //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Magnification value is %f", [event magnification]]];
        NSSize newSize;

        newSize.height = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.height * ([event magnification] + 1.0);
        newSize.width = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.width * ([event magnification] + 1.0);

        //[self setFrameSize:newSize];
        [myWebView setFrameSize:newSize];
    }


    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

[self.window setContentView:self.myWebView];

[self.window toggleFullScreen:@""];

[myWebView setMainFrameURL:@"http://www.mywebgameurl.com"];

    }


    @end
```

Evidently, the code inside `- (void)magnifyWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event` is not working. The app builds and runs, but nothing happens when I pinch.

In other words, I need to enable the webview to zoom in and out using the trackpad pinch functionality. I've already developed a very similar webview in Android, and all I had to do was add `webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);`. I'm just looking for something like that. Any help is welcome, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You just can't, Cocoa webviews doesnt have such control over pinch zoom functionality.